# Improve efficiency of iloc - merging two tables with startwith()

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two tables such as:
df1:

| ID |
| --- |
| A1A1A1 |
| A1A1A2 |
| B1B1B1 |

df2:

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| A1A1A1 | France |
| B | Egypt |
| C1C | Egypt |

In Table 2, when the ID = B, it means that all IDs starting with B will have the same country. The same applies to ID = CCC1
Hence, I cannot use pd.merge as I cannot merge on an exact match. I have written a code that seems to work (using debug) but that is incredibly slow. I am looking therefore for faster solution. My df1 has ~80K rows, df2 has ~7K rows.

Expected Output:
df2:

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| A1A1A1 | France |
| A1A1A2 | nan |
| B1B1B1 | Egypt |

Here is what I did:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
   for j in range(len(df1)):
      if df1['ID'].iloc[j].startswith(df2['ID'].iloc[i]):
        df1['Country'].iloc[j] = df2['Country'].iloc[i]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Can you build a complete set key/value pairs in your df2? If this is possible you can just use merge(). If this is not possible, is there a maximal length of your ID strings? Also, what happens if there is a ID "B1" mapping to "USA"? Is the expected output of ID "B12" "Egypt", because it starts with a "B" or USA, because it starts with "B1"?

Comment: Can you describe the ID column more? Is there a definite length/composition? For example, do they always start with letters and end with numbers?

Comment: @JasonCook In df1, all IDs have 6 characters. In df2, IDs can have anything between 1 and 6 characters. Other than the length, the format of the IDs is the same in both dfs. 
the format is: Letter-Number-Letter-Number-Letter-Number

Comment: @above_c_level The data is clean in the sense that if there is in df2, ID ='B' and Country = ' Egypt', all IDs starting with B will be mapped to Egypt. There won't be any confusion, but if it's to make the code robust, i'd like an error message. 
The ID column however, is not exactly the same, hence I cannot use the merge() function to my knowledge.

Comment: @MayankPorwal done

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to build temporary columns with all (possible) different lengths. In your case 6 columns. Then you can convert you df2 to a dictionary and just look the ids up in the dictionary. Then you combine the columns with combine_first. Be aware that the order of your column list matters with combine_first.

```py
import pandas as pd

ids = ['A1A1A1', 'A1A1A2', 'B1B1B1']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ids, columns=['ID'], index=range(3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ID': {0: 'A1A1A1', 1: 'B', 2: 'C1C'},
                              'Country': {0: 'France', 1: 'Egypt', 2: 'Egypt'}})

# build dictionary from df2 (dictionary is probably faster than .loc). Also it is cleaner
map_id_dict = df2.set_index('ID')['Country'].to_dict()

# Define target column
df1['Country'] = None
# Build temporary columns
cols = [f'ID_{i}' for i in range(1, 7)]
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    # lookup ids in dictionary from df2
    df1[col] = df1['ID'].str[:i + 1].apply(lambda x: map_id_dict.get(x))
    df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].combine_first(df1[col])
# drop temporary columns
df1 = df1.drop(columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
       ID Country
0  A1A1A1  France
1  A1A1A2    None
2  B1B1B1   Egypt
```